# Prevent user from dismissing notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, dismiss

Some apps have notifications which can´t be dismissed by swiping them away.

How can I manage such behaviour?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

In addition to Andro Selvas answer:

If you are using the **NotificationCompat.Builder**, [just use](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setOngoing(boolean))

```
builder.setOngoing(true);
```

Comment: I prefer this answer more, just because I am using Builder.

Comment: This does not work to me. It looks like it makes the notification without a "x" close button, but the swipe gesture can still be done.

Comment: Worked for me using NotificationCompat builder.

Comment: This is not working on Huawei phones, but working on Samsung

Answer (score 43):

Use the flag,`FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT` to make it persistent.

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
```

Also you can check, [FLAG_NO_CLEAR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_NO_CLEAR)

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day.

Comment: I tried to using "setOngoing(true)", but it doesn't work for me. And "FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT" work for me.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer, just additional information on the above answers.

`build.setGoing(true)` and `FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT` NO longer work on Android 14.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-all#non-dismissable-notifications

Answer (score 2):

I used the below code to make my notification persistent:

> startForeground(yourNotificationId,notificationObject);

To make it dismissable, just do the below:

> stopForeground(true);