# Music Player Lock screen widget Android

Tags: android, audio-player, android-music-player

I am implementing a Music player Application. for that Application i want to implement a playback widget that stays on their lock screens and allows them to interact with the app.

i have found that it is possible in Android 4.2 Api. but some of the music player application can provide this feature in above Android 3.0

So that i have searched a lots of thing to implementing an screen lock widget that support from Android 3.0, but i can't found anything about it.

Any one have a solution or step, how to making lock screen widget that support from Android 3.0. ?

waiting for you reply.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have you got sollution?

Answer (score 1):

You can make it into an activity instead of a widget and use certain flags such as `FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` and `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD` to achieve this I think. This thread will help you:

[Android Lock Screen Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116001/android-lock-screen-widget)

Comment: @iDroidExplorer I haven't used it personally. That thread I link has some discussion on it though. Might be of some help to you.

Comment: OK thanks for Comment. And If you found any solution of it then please let me know.