# How to put my app icon on LOCKED Screen?

Tags: android-layout

I am developing a security app. So its necessary for me to put it on lock screen. Is there a way to put it on lock screen? so that user can interact directly when needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Lock Screen Widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116001/android-lock-screen-widget)

Comment: I would suggest specifying iPhone or Android.