# New lock method for Android

Tags: android, lockscreen

I want to implement a new unlocking method for Android which is not one of the methods that come built-in in Android (i.e. not password/PIN/pattern/face etc.).

Any ideas on how to create a new lock screen (not just customize the look of an existing method)? Is there an API that allows to add a new screen lock method to the system settings?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: what do you mean by unlocking methode

Comment: AFAIK: No. Lockscreen is a protected system thing that does not allow adding possibly insecure unlocking mechanisms. The closest you can get is showing a [Lockscreen Widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116001/android-lock-screen-widget)

Comment: Xenione: I mean adding something like the face unlock that Google added. I want to add a new unlocking method based on biometric parameters similarly to face unlock.

Comment: zapl: would it be possible with a rooted phone just for demo purposes? Not planning on releasing this commercially. yet...

Comment: With a rooted devices, everything is possible. With rooted (or rather: unlocked) device you can install custom ROMs or build Android from sources

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment, you can always download the Android OS Sources and compile the OS from scratch and use the source of the lockscreen App located within the Android sources to extend it or see how the current ones are implemented.

The Android OS Sources can be found at http://source.android.com/source/building.html.

However you need certain level of experience to compile these sources.