# How to bypass the lockscreen in android.?

Tags: android, android-activity, lockscreen

I'm working on a lockscreen widget(not trying to be specific here, but Nexus 7 ) . The widget has a button which would trigger an activity.When the user clicks the button, the unlock slide symbol get's highlighted hinting the user has to slide-unlock his screen before he wants to see the button's activity. Since now, the device is locked,is there a way to bypass this and just display the activity on top of the lock screen? (not in the case of pin/pattern obviously, but only just slide)

Comment: Just found an answer :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116001/android-lock-screen-widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was searching a lot for a way to do it. We need to use flags in while giving an intent to the widget button. More information here.

[Android Lock Screen Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116001/android-lock-screen-widget)