# API to customize android lock screen when my application running

Tags: android, api, lockscreen

I want the user's phone to have a different background image or widgets on the lock screen when my application is running on the user's device.Is it possible to do it in android. If yes would someone please suggest me a way to do that .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Some Spacewhales here

[Android Lock Screen Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116001/android-lock-screen-widget)

Also some Spacewhales

here and here

Answer (score 0):

Try this it might helpful. Standard android widget http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#lockscreen

[Android Lock Screen Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116001/android-lock-screen-widget)