# Android secure screen

Tags: android, screenshot, screen-capture

I need to make an application with functionality that demands a secure screen in terms of preventing screenshots and screen recording. Now, i know WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE prevents standard screenshots, but will it successfully  block 3rd party app screenshots, and is there a way to block screen recording software as well (e.g. game video recording software)?

Thank you!

Comment: Please check this  . I hope it will helps 

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116001/android-lock-screen-widget

Comment: Thank you, but what i need is to show something on screen, and have it secured from any form of screen capture. While the link you provided is informative, my concern are 3rd party apps for screen capture and an effective mechanism to block them while my app is on screen, if there is such mechanism at all.

Comment: What content are you trying to protect? Is it that sensitive that you need to prevent all types of screen capture? You know that someone could just use one device to take pictures or record a video from the device that is running your app, so any form of protection is useless IMHO.

Comment: That is exactly what i need - to prevent all types of screen capture. I know that someone can always take a photo, but for now this is what i need.

Comment: Sorry, there's no way you can protect your app from screen capture.

Comment: Does this work at all then?

`WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE`