# Android - Create lock screen audio player

Tags: android, audio-streaming, audio-player, lockscreen

I created an android app that has a streaming audio. I need to create an audio player on the lock screen to continue running in the background. What is the best option for this? Should I create a widget?

Answer (score 2):

For android 4.2 and above you can use the official lock screen widget which is documented over here - [App Widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#lockscreen)

And there is already a thread present which contains some discussion if the version is below 4.2  : 
[Android Lock Screen Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116001/android-lock-screen-widget)