# How to create lock screen notifications in my app?

Tags: android, custom-notification, lockscreenwidget

I'm trying to create a custom notification in my android app with an image that will also be visible when the phone is locked.

Right now, Im building push notifications which are visible on the notification bar only,  in which only my app icon is visible and on clicking which a certain pending intent is executed.

Is there a way through which i can show, my notifications with an image and a headline with it and also it gets visible on locked screen .

Also is there any widgets available or particular libraries through which i can implement my custom notifications?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `alertdialog` with a flag. The `flag_show_when_locked` is the thing you trying to do I suppose. Please refer to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4666109/2253883).

Comment: My main focus is through the notifications. Im not able understand , how can i use alertDialog to implement notification